# Roll/Dice command?

Tags: javascript, random, discord.js

I'm trying to make roll command that generates a random number based on user input.

For example:

> user: `!roll 1d100`
> bot: `Your output is 65` (or some other random number)

I have tried a couple of different things, but none of them have worked, the output was "NaN".

My nearest code was:

```javascript
const argsminus8 = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const commandminus8 = argsminus8.shift().toLowerCase();

if(message.content.startsWith (prefix + `random-number`)) {
  function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
  if (!argsminus8.length) {
    return message.channel.send(`What roll am I supposed to make?`);
  }
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Number:')
    .setDescription( getRandomIntInclusive())
    .setColor(0x0099ff)
    .setTimestamp()
  message.channel.send({ embed });
}
```

Comment: NaN means “not a number”

Comment: You are not sending parameters for the function getRandomIntInclusive. Try sending the min and max values, something like `.setDescription( getRandomIntInclusive(100, 1000))`.

Comment: If you create a function that takes parameters, you have to set said parameters.

Comment: I am trying to make it customizable for user, if someone uses command !random-number 1 5 then bot sends random number between 1 and 5, if someone types !random-number 1 10 then bot sends random number between 1 and 10 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a function that takes in parameters you have to use those.

```
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
        min = Math.min(min, max);
        max = Math.max(max, min);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    let num1 = argsminus8[0];
    let num2 = argsminus8[1];
    if(!num1) return message.reply("Please enter a first number");
    if(!num2) return message.reply("Please enter a second number"); 

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Number:')
        .setDescription(getRandomIntInclusive(num1, num2))
        .setColor(0x0099ff)
        .setTimestamp()
    message.channel.send({ embed });
```

Implement this inside `if(message.content.startsWith (prefix + 'random-number'))`.
This will create random numbers between 1 and 100, because for the `min` parameter I said 1 and for the `max` parameter I said 100.
You can change the numbers to whatever you like.

Comment: Yes but I am trying to make it customizable for user, if someone uses command !random-number 1 5 then bot sends random number between 1 and 5, if someone types !random-number 1 10 then bot sends random number between 1 and 10 etc.

Comment: @ZayrenTV I edited the code above. I simply created two variables which are storing the input numbers. Then I gave these two numbers into your created function, as it takes two parameters. Now the user can put in 2 numbers and it will create a random number between those.

Comment: Note to everyone else that wants to use this code:
You need to make argsminus8 and commandminus8 consts above the command like this:
```const argsminus8 = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const commandminus8 = argsminus8.shift().toLowerCase();```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest answer is that in your `getRandomIntInclusive`, variables `min` and `max` have the value of `undefined`. In JavaScript every arithmetic operation with a non-numeric (NaN) value results in `NaN`.

Why `undefined`? Because your function is expecting those two parameters (`min` and `max`) when used:

```js
// Wrong
getRandomIntInclusive();

// Correct
getRandomIntInclusive(1, 100)
```

Also, if you are calling your function `Int` (from Integer) there's no need to `.ceil()` or `.floor()` since both methods round the fractional part to the nearest integer and, as far as I know, **you don't need a random number between 0.97 and 99.01**.

If your only issue is that `NaN` result, you can simplify your code a lot by using the advice I gave you, and maybe using a more common dice (a random number between 1 and 6)

```js
/**
* Simplified randomizer method
*/
const getRandomIntInclusive = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

console.log(getRandomIntInclusive(1,6));
```

Comment: Yes but I am trying to make it customizable for user, if someone uses command !random-number 1 5 then bot sends random number between 1 and 5, if someone types !random-number 1 10 then bot sends random number between 1 and 10 etc.